# Efficient way of replacing a key in list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

What is the best list comprehension method of replacing keys with a prefix of "ble_mac_"  as "ble_mac" in a list of dictionary?

```
Given List : [{'ble_mac_2': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '818'}, 
              {'ble_mac_2': 'DCDC9FD25476', 'location': '819'}, 
              {'ble_mac_3': 'DCDC9FD25473', 'location': '819'}, 
              {'ble_mac_4': 'DCDC9FD25474', 'location': '819'}]

Expected List : [{'ble_mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '818'}, 
                 {'ble_mac': 'DCDC9FD25476', 'location': '819'}, 
                 {'ble_mac': 'DCDC9FD25473', 'location': '819'}, 
                 {'ble_mac': 'DCDC9FD25474', 'location': '819'}]
```

Comment: Avoid using `IN` as the name, as it is keyword.

Comment: what if the key is other than `ble_mac` ?

Comment: if the key is other than ble_mac, it can be left as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of list and dict comprehension, and apply a substitution via regular expression:

```
import re
lst = [{ re.sub("^ble_mac_.*", "ble_mac", k): v for k, v in d.items()} for d in lst]
```

Without regular expression it would probably run a bit faster:

```
lst = [{ "ble_mac" if k.startswith("ble_mac_") else k: v for k, v in d.items()} for d in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

By using nested `list` and `dictionary` comprehensions.

```
Extected_List = [{'ble_mac' if 'ble_mac' in k[0:7] else k:v for k,v in i.items()} for i in Given_List]
Expected_List
    [{'ble_mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '818'},
     {'ble_mac': 'DCDC9FD25476', 'location': '819'},
     {'ble_mac': 'DCDC9FD25473', 'location': '819'},
     {'ble_mac': 'DCDC9FD25474', 'location': '819'}]
```

Comment: The difference I see with my answer is your use of `'ble_mac' in k`. Just be aware that this also matches keys like `ble_macdonald` and `prefix_ble_mac_1`.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your feedback. Always appreciated. I did the change now. It will take care of the boundary condition you expounded upon.